# Creating a popup on link click?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to create a popup that is only displayed when a link is clicked. This is the code I have but the problem is the dialog is shown when the page loads, rather than when clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 250, width:200 });
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>Dialog Contents here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can hide dialog div on load with ($("#dialog").hide();)

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>
        Dialog Contents here</p>
</div>
```

Set

```
  style='display:none'
```

Comment: adding the style="display:none;" doesn't work. It is still shown on Page load.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that is. I have never done anything like this before

Comment: Using This is URL. http://jsfiddle.net/
put your HTML in html section and script in javascript section,
you can save it, after save copy URL and send it to anyone you want. you can also test it by clicking Run button

Comment: Did you see you issue regenerating there?
or you just want to remove "Dialog Contents here" on load right? there is no popup displayed
I have updated that :http://jsfiddle.net/StPMu/1/ now clicking on the Click here popup will be displayed. then let me know where did u stuck

Comment: The issue does not regenerate on there, only on my webpage. I just want the "Dialog contents here" to not be visible when the page loads, like it does on the Fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27639/discussion-between-the-val-and-user2212460)

Comment: Then the solution i have given is exact pal, see i have resolved your issue in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/StPMu/2/

Comment: The issue is still not resolved on my actual website. What you have given me works in Fiddle but not on my site. I cannot see any reason for this though

Answer (score 0):

At First Set display property like display:none;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
$("#dialog").show();
        $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 250, width:200 });
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
<div id="dialog"  style="display:none;"title="Dialog Title">
<p>Dialog Contents here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to call a function instead :

```
var dialogBox = function()  {
   $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 250, width:200 });
};
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
        dialogBox();
    });
});
```

In HTML :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style='display:none;'>
    <p>Dialog Contents here</p>
</div>
```